# Error while installing coreui laravel vue admin panel template

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, core-ui

I want to use the coreui laravel vuejs admin panel template. I have downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-laravel-admin-template and unzipped it to my wampserver64. My php version is 7.3.12, Apache Version is 2.4.41 and MySql version is 8.0.18. My system is windows 10 Home edition. After unzip the file I have followed the steps mentioned in the above url. I have run successfully run the commands `npm install` from coreui directory and `composer install` from laravel directory. Then I have renamed the `.env.example` file to .env and added the MySql database details as
follows,

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=coreui
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

My phpmyadmin login username is `"root"` and there is no password set. The MySql is running in port number 3308.

I have created a database named coreui. Then I run the commands `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan jwt:secret`. Both executed successfully. But when I run the `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` command, the execution starts and after some time it exits with an exception which is as follows,

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'description' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `example` (`name`, `description`, `status_id`) values (Quae quo alias., Et dolorem vitae autem dolore explicabo nostrum aspernatur. Rem architecto eveniet quam. Similique fuga veritatis asperiores dolorem earum consequatur. Aut fugit labore culpa mollitia quo omnis., 3))
```

I have tried with setting the defaultStringLength to 191 in the AppServiceProvider.php in the app bundle, but no luck. After updating the AppServiceProvider.php here is my code,

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

I am a front end developer and new to the vuejs. I don't have any knowledge in laravel. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: what type is that `description` field?

Comment: It was given as 'string' initially. When I changed it to 'longText' the issue fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your're using a VARCHAR in your DB, for what the given text is too long.

Try to set the column to a longText with the following:

```
$table->longText('description');
```

Comment: It worked. It was given as 'string' in laravel\database\migrations\2020_01_21_161243_create_example_table.php. When I changed it to 'longText' the issue fixed. Thank you